# Android/Kotlin, how to reduce duplicated part of this code

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a library author and have to intercept all touch events of child views, by overriding ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent().

First I wrote the following code (simplified):

```
interface touchIntercepter {
    // my library set this field to intercept touch event
    var touchHandler: ((MotionEvent) -> Boolean)?
}

class LinearLayoutTouchIntercepter @JvmOverloads constructor (
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
 )
    : touchIntercepter
    , LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
{
    override var touchHandler: ((MotionEvent) -> Boolean)? = null

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent) = touchHandler?.invoke(event) ?: false
}
```

Library users can use the LinearLayoutTouchInterceptor in their layout xml file instead of standard LinearLayout and then my library code can intercept touch event of the user layout's child views by touchIntercepter interface.

I think it is wonderful if there's something like ViewGroup.setOnInterceptTouchListener(), like View.setOnClickListener(), but I found that there isn't.

Now the problem is, I want to provide the same functionality for RelativeLayout, FrameLayout and other ViewGroup descendants.

For example,

```
class RelativeLayoutTouchIntercepter @JvmOverloads constructor (
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
 )
    : touchIntercepter
    , RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
{
    override var touchHandler: ((MotionEvent) -> Boolean)? = null

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent) = touchHandler?.invoke(event) ?: false
}
```

As you can see, all code is the same but the only difference is inheriting XXXXXLayout instead of LinearLayout. I don't want to copy and paste them but have no idea how to reduce the duplication.

It seems that Kotlin generics are not helping in this case while C++ template perfectly can help like this pseudo code :

```
template <typename T>
class TouchInterceptorTmpl : public T
{
    void onInterceptTouchEvent() override;
};

using RelativeLayoutTouchInterceptor = TouchInterceptorTmpl<RelativeLayout>;
using FrameLayoutTouchInterceptor = TouchInterceptorTmpl<FrameLayout>;
```

No way to do like this in Kotlin?

Comment: Do you wants to change the super class dynamically ?

Comment: @Stephan J No, it is statically decided in user's layout xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce duplication a little bit by making a concrete implementation of your interface and using it as a delegate. Unfortunately, you can't avoid overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent` in each implementation due to how inheritance works, but you can make an extension function for your interface to shorten that code a bit.

Note, interface names in Kotlin are capitalized by convention.

Setup:

```
interface TouchInterceptor {
    var touchInterceptionHandler: ((MotionEvent) -> Boolean)?
}

class TouchInterceptorImpl: TouchInterceptor {
    override var touchInterceptionHandler: ((MotionEvent) -> Boolean)? = null
}

fun TouchInterceptor.intercept(event: MotionEvent): Boolean = touchInterceptionHandler?.invoke(event) ?: false
```

Usage:

```
class RelativeLayoutTouchIntercepter @JvmOverloads constructor (
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
 )
    : TouchInterceptor by TouchInterceptorImpl()
    , RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
{
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean = intercept(event)
}
```